# create own plugins or add on for netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

is it possible to create a plugin or add on for netbeans such that whenever i run or compile a project, a pop up box shows me that run complete or build complete. I know i can create a pop up box using java. this is just to know, consider something like learning process.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you can do something like so, please take a look at [this](http://platform.netbeans.org/tutorials/nbm-google.html) Netbeans Plugin Tutorial.

However, what you are requesting, a *build complete notification* is already available through Netbean's Console output window. Also, popups can get pretty annoying pretty fast, so be careful.

Comment: thnx... its just to learn as it can be applied to various applications.

Comment: if i create a plugin through netbeans module, does it work whenever or whatever project i compile or run?

Comment: @Raj Unfortunately I have no experience with Netbeans modules, but I would assume that as long as your plugin is compatible with the same Netbeans version you are running, as long as you are running Netbeans, you should get the same behavior regardless of what project you are doing.